# How to create my installer which will be cross platform in java

Tags: java, installation

Hi I want to create a cross platform installer in java.
How to create.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 3):

You want to create an installer or use one?  I'm assuming you want to package an application and have it deployable across different architectures.

My team had good success with [lzPack](http://izpack.org/).  It's free and open source.  Another alternative would be Java's [Web Start](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/javawebstart/index.jsp).

Comment: actually i have created a swing application and created its jar. Now i want to create installer for that jar file (means i want to create installable version of that jar. so how to achieve this)

Comment: We use IzPack and it works adequate for what we need, but the application is still in the early-adopter phase. Adding your own code is cumbersome and the documentation is only marginal.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this: [Open Source Installers Generators in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/installer-generators)

Answer (score 0):

[AntInstaller](http://antinstaller.sourceforge.net/) works well. Because it's based on Ant you can do a user-friendly GUI installer and/or a shell-based headless install.

Comment: Looks interesting, but I see the last release was Jan 2007.

Comment: So are you suggesting it's not supported ? You can also derive from the above that it's mature and largely feature-complete, can't you ?

Comment: We use antinstaller. It's quite good, but has it's limitations and there are some bugs that are not solved since development stopped a long time ago